# How to extract fields of anonymous row type in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, composite-types

In PostgreSQL I can create an anonymous row or composite type

```
postgres=# SELECT ROW(1,'Hello',false) as r;
      r
-------------
 (1,Hello,f)
(1 row)
```

But how can I get the fields out again?  None of the following work

```
postgres=# SELECT (r).* from (SELECT ROW(1,'Hello',false) as r) as T;
ERROR:  record type has not been registered

postgres=# SELECT (r).column0 from (SELECT ROW(1,'Hello',false) as r) as T;
ERROR:  record type has not been registered
```

Comment: "*But how can I get the fields out again*"  - you can't unless you cast the anonymous record to a know (record) type.

Comment: See [ROW constructors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS), especially its example code.

Answer (score 10):

[New in v13](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/release-13.html#:%7E:text=Allow%20ROW%20expressions%20to%20have%20their%20members%20extracted%20with%20suffix%20notation)

> - Allow [`ROW expressions`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) to have their members extracted with suffix notation (Tom Lane)
>
>   For example, `(ROW(4, 5.0)).f1` now returns 4.

```sql
select (ROW(1,'Hello',false)).f1
```

Note there are some gotchas. You may need to explicitly cast type

```sql
select (ROW(1,'Hello',false)).f2
```

> ERROR:  failed to find conversion function from unknown to text

```sql
select (ROW(1,'Hello'::text,false)).f2
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9fe759a8732781061b86f283a2f2364d) for more

The relevant commit in source appears to be [8b7a0f1d11](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/8b7a0f1d11) with a discussion at https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/10872.1572202006%40sss.pgh.pa.us

I don't know at this time of any official documentation, but I'll [shout out Jack@TA](https://topanswers.xyz/transcript?room=2&id=72490&year=2020&month=10#c72490) for showing me the new trick.

Comment: Somehow I wasn't able to understand the original documentation. before reading this question and your explanation. Thanks Peter!