# How to extract anonymous row type fields from window function result in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Context: [This question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/273559/how-to-extract-fields-of-anonymous-row-type-in-postgresql) deals with extracting anonymous row type fields in general. The top answer notes that in v13, this was enabled:

> Allow ROW expressions to have their members extracted with suffix notation (Tom Lane)

And sure enough, this works:

```
# select (a).* from (select (1, 'a'::text)) t(a);
 f1 | f2 
----+----
  1 | a
(1 row)
```

But once the inner record is returned from a window function, its fields are no longer accessible:

```
# select (a).* from (select first_value((1, 'a'::text)) over ()) t(a);
ERROR:  record type has not been registered
```

Trying to annotate it with a record type yields

```
# select (a).* from (select (first_value((1, 'a')) over ())::record(int, text)) t(a);
ERROR:  type modifier is not allowed for type "record"
```

Is there a way to make this work without having to explicitly define a custom type?

Answer (score 2):

My first attempt would be to try to get the record/row object into a more amenable type. Consider my usage of `row_to_json` below:

```
SELECT r->>'f1' AS f1, r->>'f2' AS f2 
FROM (SELECT row_to_json(first_value((1, 'a'::TEXT)) OVER ()) AS r) AS t;
```

and that produces:

| f1 | f2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |

which seems like we are on the right track. What is going on here?
Consider the query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT first_value((1, 'a'::text)) OVER ()) as fv(a, b);
```

which returns the error:

```
ERROR:  table "fv" has 1 columns available but 2 columns specified
```

If we look at the following, the aliasing should make a good deal more sense:

```
SELECT fv, a FROM (SELECT first_value((1, 'a'::text)) OVER ()) as fv(a);
```

| fv | a |
| --- | --- |
| ("(1,a)") | (1,a) |

Here, `fv` is a `FIELD` containing a `RECORD`, and `a` is a `RECORD`. Neither are a primitive, - or simple. (see https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/parser/parse_target.c#L1432)

So the best I can offer is to cast the `RECORD` to `JSON`, but that *feels* wrong, but why the dot notation is not sufficient? ie. `(fv.a).f1` ?

More illumination comes from https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/9073.1262556393%40sss.pgh.pa.us where they encounter the same issue using `ROW`, which is equivalent to:

```
SELECT row_to_json(fv)->>'f1' AS f1, row_to_json(fv)->>'f2' AS f2 
FROM (SELECT ROW (1, 'a'::text)  AS fv) AS c;
```

producing:

| f1 | f2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |

See the PGSQL source:
https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/parser/parse_target.c#L1584
and
https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/fmgr/funcapi.c#L566

Comment: Thank you for entertaining the question. The email you linked seems to have been sent by the same person who was later credited for supporting ad-hoc record field access. Can confirm that the `row_to_json` trick works even with rows returned from window functions.